# Default Column in SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, column

I am not sure what it is called, but I want to change the Key column so that the Open Menu is on a different column.  The column it is in now is going to be a hidden column.

Answer (score 0):

Open the list in SP Designer, and search for the field that you want to have the menu in `<ViewFields>` tag and add linkToItem="TRUE"

```
<FieldRef Name="NewColumn" linkToItem="TRUE"/>
```